# Juno 5.0 to Hera 5.1 upgrade not working

Tags: release-hera

Anyone had any issues with upgrading from Juno to Hera? 
I tried to update both ways (GUI and command line) but i keep getting the response "all packages are up-to-date"

My system is running the latest kernel 5.0.0-37-generic
I'm lost at this point, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please check your system's about from the settings and see if its upgraded already.

Comment: @Hasan I've rebooted a few times and it still shows that the system is running Juno 5.0 but the latest kernel version.